# Non blocking boost io_service for deadline_timers

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

After reading the documentation for boost::asio::deadline_timer, it seems io_service::run() and the handler method are called on the same thread.  Is there any method to create a timer on one thread while running the io_service object on the background thread?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can run as many IO threads with your service as you wish. So, if you want to signal a background thread every once in a while, just raise a condition variable or something?

Comment: Thanks sehe for your answer. Actually it was required to make the thread making the callback as non blocking. in normal inplementation it will be blocked till the time timer expires as soon as we call io_service::run() method. So both thread needed to be independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fun and glory here's how to combine a thread queue with asio deadline timer to dispatch non-blocking tasks from a deadline timer:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f47f4e19e74f5e7c)</kbd>**

```
#ifndef HEADER_GUARD_CUSTOM_THREADPOOL_HPP
#define HEADER_GUARD_CUSTOM_THREADPOOL_HPP
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <deque>

namespace custom {
    using namespace boost;

    class thread_pool
    {
    private:
        mutex mx;
        condition_variable cv;

        typedef function<void()> job_t;
        std::deque<job_t> _queue;

        thread_group pool;

        boost::atomic_bool shutdown;
        static void worker_thread(thread_pool& q)
        {
            while (optional<job_t> job = q.dequeue())
                (*job)();
        }

    public:
        thread_pool() : shutdown(false) {
            //LOG_INFO_MESSAGE << "Number of possible Threads: " << boost::thread::hardware_concurrency() << std::endl;
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < boost::thread::hardware_concurrency(); ++i){
                pool.create_thread(bind(worker_thread, ref(*this)));
            }
        }

        void enqueue(job_t job)
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lk(mx);
            _queue.push_back(job);

            cv.notify_one();
        }

        optional<job_t> dequeue()
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lk(mx);
            namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

            cv.wait(lk, phx::ref(shutdown) || !phx::empty(phx::ref(_queue)));

            if (_queue.empty())
                return none;

            job_t job = _queue.front();
            _queue.pop_front();
            return job;
        }

        ~thread_pool()
        {
            shutdown = true;
            {
                lock_guard<mutex> lk(mx);
                cv.notify_all();
            }

            pool.join_all();
        }
    };
}

#endif // HEADER_GUARD_CUSTOM_THREADPOOL_HPP
```

And the simple test program:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace a = boost::asio;
using error = boost::system::error_code;

void timer_loop(a::deadline_timer& tim, custom::thread_pool& pool) {
    static boost::atomic_int count(0);

    tim.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10));
    tim.async_wait([&](error ec) {
        if (!ec && (++count < 100)) {
            int id = count;

            pool.enqueue([id] { 
                std::cout << "timer callback " << id << " started on thread " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
                boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(rand()%1000));
                std::cout << "timer callback " << id << " completed\n";
            });

            std::cout << "Job " << id << " enqueued" << "\n";
            timer_loop(tim, pool);
        }
    });
}

int main()
{
    a::io_service svc;
    a::deadline_timer tim(svc);
    custom::thread_pool pool;

    timer_loop(tim, pool);

    svc.run();
}
```