# Application of boost::asio

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, signals, boost-asio

```
void ahaConnector::asyncWriteData(vector<uint8_t> packedMessage) {

    cout<<"\n async write data packed messagbace";



    deviceStreamDescriptor.assign(device);

    boost::asio::write (
                       deviceStreamDescriptor,
                       boost::asio::buffer(packedMessage)
                       );


    readbuffer.resize(1024);
    deviceStreamDescriptor.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(readbuffer),
                                boost::bind(&ahaConnector::readHeader, this,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::error(),
                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred()
                                ));

    io_service.run();



}


void ahaConnector::readHeader(const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {


    if(!ec) {

        std::cout<<"\n Bytes transfereed :"<<bytes_transferred<<" "<<readbuffer.size();
        cout<<endl;
        vector<uint8_t> packedMessage;
        packedMessage.resize(bytes_transferred);
        packedMessage = readbuffer;

        deviceStreamDescriptor.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(readbuffer),
                                        boost::bind(&ahaConnector::readHeader, this,
                                        boost::asio::placeholders::error(),
                                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred()

                                        ));

    }
    else {

        cout<<"\n System Error Code "<<ec;
    }



}
```

I have successfully performed async I/O using boost::asio on a Single Thread which effectively doesn't  serve the prpose.

1. My Main threads does an asyncWrite to  a device file
2. I would like a Reader Thread ( lifetime that of Application ) that reads , provides a callback to the readHandler in the same Thread
3. Now I need to somehow notify a third thread 'Callback Thread' that Reader thread have recieved data.

I tried creating seperate threads for Reader and Writer with diffrent file descriptors it doesnt work , I gues lack of sync.

I would like a seperate thread for io_service, which is reused again everytime asyncwriteData pushes some data onto the io_service thread and io_service thread will push some data onto a Callback thread.

PS : I have seen enough solutions , but I would like a single io_service thread throught the application lifetime

Challenges I am facing :

1. Create a global thread that is initially idle and the assign work to them.
2. Should i have a Reader Writer Threads or a single thread for io_service

Comment: What will be the wage?

Comment: _Please let me know a **viable** solution with code_...lol

Comment: Anyways, maybe this can serve as inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26730114/85371

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a coding-slave command.

Comment: Peeps, FTR: I have upvoted this question. I just didn't condone the "lazy attitude" that might be a result of language barriers or just naivetee. I'm perfectly willing to answer, I was just not going to create the whole thing out of thin air.

Comment: Re: edit "I have seen enough solutions , but I would like a single io_service thread throught the application lifetime", what's stopping you? What's the relevance of the code to the question bullets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

1. separate `io_service` with distinct threads for the WriteThread, ReadThread and CallbackThread
2. or use a single `io_service` instance with a thread pool and three `strand`s

The first gives your tasks "thread affinity". The second reduces required locking and provides potentially better scalability.

Observations:

- Whether or not you use Signals is immaterial (AFAIK it doesn't do thread-specific callback invocation)
- `io_service` objects are completely thread safe so you can perfectly use them as task queues
- `strands` are *logical threads* in that they serialize the work on the strand, without necessarily running individual tasks on the same thread
- here is a demo of using Asio with a callback to a background thread using a thread-queue: [Non blocking boost io_service for deadline_timers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720271/non-blocking-boost-io-service-for-deadline-timers/26730114#26730114)

Comment: Would the downvoter kindly explain what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: thanks for ur support , have edited my question