# Reorder boost handlers after post

Tags: multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I would like to reorder the handlers processed by a boost io_service:

This is my pseudocode:

```
start()
{
   io.run();
}

thread1()
{
   io.post(myhandler1);
}

thread2()
{
   io.post(myhandler2);
}
```

thread1() and thread2() are called independently.

In this case, the io_service processes the handler in the post order.

Queue example: myhandler1|myhandler1|myhandler2|myhandler1|myhandler2

How to modify the io_service processing order to execute myhandler1 and myhandler2 one after the other ?

New Queue example: myhandler1|myhandler2|myhandler1|myhandler2|myhandler1

I wrote this code but CPU usage is 100%:

```
start()
{
   while(1)
   {
     io1.poll_one();
     io2.poll_one();
   }
}

thread1()
{
   io1.post(myhandler1);
}

thread2()
{
   io2.post(myhandler2);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use two queues. From this ASIO anwer I made once ([Non blocking boost io_service for deadline_timers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720271/non-blocking-boost-io-service-for-deadline-timers/26730114#26730114)) I took the `thread_pool` class.

I split it into `task_queue` and `thread_pool` classes.

I created a `worker` type that knows how to juggle two queues:

```
struct worker {
    task_queue q1, q2;

    void wake() {
        q1.wake();
        q2.wake();
    }

    void operator()(boost::atomic_bool& shutdown) {
        std::cout << "Worker start\n";
        while (true) {
            auto job1 = q1.dequeue(shutdown);
            if (job1) (*job1)();

            auto job2 = q2.dequeue(shutdown);
            if (job2) (*job2)();

            if (shutdown && !(job1 || job2))
                break;
        }
        std::cout << "Worker exit\n";
    }
};
```

You can see how the worker loop is structured so that - if tasks are enqueued - queues will be served in alternation.

> Note: the `wake()` call is there for reliable shutdown; the queues use blocking waits, and hence they will need to be signaled (*woken up*) when the `shutdown` flag is toggled.

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e410044a5b9031e1)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

namespace custom {
    using namespace boost;

    class task_queue {
    private:
        mutex mx;
        condition_variable cv;

        typedef function<void()> job_t;
        std::deque<job_t> _queue;

    public:
        void enqueue(job_t job)
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lk(mx);
            _queue.push_back(job);

            cv.notify_one();
        }

        template <typename T>
        optional<job_t> dequeue(T& shutdown)
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lk(mx);

            cv.wait(lk, [&] { return shutdown || !_queue.empty(); });

            if (_queue.empty())
                return none;

            job_t job = _queue.front();
            _queue.pop_front();
            return job;
        }

        void wake() {
            lock_guard<mutex> lk(mx);
            cv.notify_all();
        }
    };

    template <typename Worker> class thread_pool
    {
    private:
        thread_group       _pool;
        boost::atomic_bool _shutdown { false };
        Worker             _worker;

        void start() {
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < 1 /*boost::thread::hardware_concurrency()*/; ++i){
                std::cout << "Creating thread " << i << "\n";
                _pool.create_thread([&] { _worker(_shutdown); });
            }
        }
    public:
        thread_pool() { start(); }

        ~thread_pool() {
            std::cout << "Pool going down\n";
            _shutdown = true;
            _worker.wake();
            _pool.join_all();
        }

        Worker& get_worker() { return _worker; }
    };

    struct worker {
        task_queue q1, q2;

        void wake() {
            q1.wake();
            q2.wake();
        }

        void operator()(boost::atomic_bool& shutdown) {
            std::cout << "Worker start\n";
            while (true) {
                auto job1 = q1.dequeue(shutdown);
                if (job1) (*job1)();

                auto job2 = q2.dequeue(shutdown);
                if (job2) (*job2)();

                if (shutdown && !(job1 || job2))
                    break;
            }
            std::cout << "Worker exit\n";
        }
    };
}

void croak(char const* queue, int i) {
    static boost::mutex cout_mx;
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lk(cout_mx);
    std::cout << "thread " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << " " << queue << " task " << i << "\n"; 
}

int main() {
    custom::thread_pool<custom::worker> pool;

    auto& queues = pool.get_worker();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) queues.q1.enqueue([i] { croak("q1", i); });
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) queues.q2.enqueue([i] { croak("q2", i); });
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
Creating thread 0
Pool going down
Worker start
thread 7f7311397700 q1 task 1
thread 7f7311397700 q2 task 1
thread 7f7311397700 q1 task 2
thread 7f7311397700 q2 task 2
thread 7f7311397700 q1 task 3
thread 7f7311397700 q2 task 3
thread 7f7311397700 q1 task 4
thread 7f7311397700 q2 task 4
thread 7f7311397700 q1 task 5
thread 7f7311397700 q2 task 5
thread 7f7311397700 q1 task 6
thread 7f7311397700 q2 task 6
thread 7f7311397700 q1 task 7
thread 7f7311397700 q2 task 7
thread 7f7311397700 q1 task 8
thread 7f7311397700 q2 task 8
thread 7f7311397700 q1 task 9
thread 7f7311397700 q2 task 9
thread 7f7311397700 q1 task 10
thread 7f7311397700 q2 task 10
Worker exit
```

### Generalizing it

Here it is generalized for more queues (e.g. three):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c5b9ae22b1b64c3)</kbd>**

---

Note that the above have 1 worker thread servicing; if you created more than 1 thread, each thread *individually* would alternate between queues, but overall the order would be undefined (because the thread scheduling is undefined).

The generalized version is *somewhat* more accurate here since it shared the `idx` variable between worker threads, but the actual output order still depends on thread scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`run_one()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run_one/overload1.html) instead of `poll_one()` should work (note that [`reset()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html) is also required):

```
start()
{
   while(1)
   {
     io1.run_one();
     io2.run_one();

     io1.reset();
     io2.reset();
   }
}
```

However, I don't know if this is a *good* solution to any actual problem you might have. This is one of those cases where the question, "What are you really trying to do?" seems relevant. For example, if it makes sense to run `handler2` after every invocation of `handler1`, then perhaps `handler1` should invoke `handler2`.